# Can a jax-ws web service use an rpc type call and receive raw xml?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jax-ws

I have a web service that I've been working on and it's wokrring fine so far by creating a port in the client and then calling a method on the port. However, I've just been told that a couple of the clients who will be using the web service plan on sending it raw xml based based off of the schemas used by the web service and I was wondering if this was possible. I think I may need to use the provider interface to make the web service capable of handling this type of request but I'm not sure.

I've done a search of the questions here but none of them seemed to answer my question and what I find on the net after googling says that it's possible but they then proceed with examples that work the exact same way as what I already have.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: By raw XML, do you mean just on top of TCP, not over HTTP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> plan on sending it raw xml based based off of the schemas used by the web service

So you mean they plan on sending you XML messages based on the schema published in your web service's WSDL?

This is exactly what SOAP is and how SOAP/XML web services work.

Assuming the clients are sending your properly formed messages, these client's requests are identical to requests from any other client and you shouldn't have to do anything special for them.

Comment: Yes. The xml they wens will be created from the schema published with the wsdl.so they can use the web service by creating a port and calling a method on it or send it XML created from the schema?

Comment: It's all the same under the covers. You might want to read up a bit on what web service clients actually do, SOAP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to send and receive XMLs across

here is 1 way

http://java.dzone.com/articles/implementing-jax-ws-web