# Passing xml to jax rpc web service

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl, xml-serialization, jax-rpc

I have a jax-rpc web service. When i try to pass xml to the web service the following error occurs:

```
[3/18/12 4:26:27:947 IST] 0000002b WebServicesSe E     com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.WebServicesServlet doPost WSWS3227E:  Error:     Exception:
                                 WebServicesFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.generalException
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: WSWS3084E: Error: SimpleDeserializer     encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to  deserialize. Message being parsed: 
 faultActor: null
 faultDetail: 

org.xml.sax.SAXException: WSWS3084E: Error: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize. Message being parsed: 
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.WebServicesFault.makeFault(WebServicesFault.java:298)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.SOAPPart._getSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:1090)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:628)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.SOAPPart.getEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:656)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.handlers.jaxrpc.JAXRPCHandlerChain.handleRequest(JAXRPCHandlerChain.java:301)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.handlers.jaxrpc.JAXRPCHandler.invokeServerRequestHandler(JAXRPCHandler.java:506)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.handlers.jaxrpc.JAXRPCHandler$1.invoke(JAXRPCHandler.java:380)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.PivotHandlerWrapper.invoke(PivotHandlerWrapper.java:209)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.WebServicesEngine.invoke(WebServicesEngine.java:336)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.WebServicesServlet.doPost(WebServicesServlet.java:908)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.WebServicesServletBase.service(WebServicesServletBase.java:344)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
```

A similar error is described here

[Can a jax-ws web service use an rpc type call and receive raw xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955495/can-a-jax-ws-web-service-use-an-rpc-type-call-and-receive-raw-xml)

but in the previous post, the raw xml is based based off of the schemas used by the web service. Here, there is no specific schema used by the input.

The WSDL file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://service.session.plh"     xmlns:impl="http://service.session.plh" xmlns:intf="http://service.session.plh" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsi="http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1/xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <wsdl:types>
 <schema targetNamespace="http://service.session.plh" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <element name="AddPatientResponse">
 <complexType>
  <sequence>
  <element name="AddPatientReturn" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
  </sequence>
 </complexType>
 </element>
 <element name="AddPatient">
 <complexType>
 <sequence>
  <element name="patientform" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
 </sequence>
 </complexType>
 </element>
 </schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name="AddPatientRequest">
 <wsdl:part element="impl:AddPatient" name="parameters">
 </wsdl:part>

</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="AddPatientResponse">
 <wsdl:part element="impl:AddPatientResponse" name="parameters">
</wsdl:part>

</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="StaffBean">
 <wsdl:operation name="AddPatient">
   <wsdl:input message="impl:AddPatientRequest" name="AddPatientRequest">
</wsdl:input>

   <wsdl:output message="impl:AddPatientResponse" name="AddPatientResponse">
</wsdl:output>

</wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="StaffSoapBinding" type="impl:StaffBean">
<wsaw:UsingAddressing wsdl:required="false" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"/>
 <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
 <wsdl:operation name="AddPatient">
   <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="AddPatient"/>
   <wsdl:input name="AddPatientRequest">
     <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
   </wsdl:input>
   <wsdl:output name="AddPatientResponse">
     <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="StaffService">
 <wsdl:port binding="impl:StaffSoapBinding" name="Staff">
   <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:9080/PLHospitalService/services/Staff"/>
 </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. Pls reply ASAP. Will vote for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please provide the SOAP request you are calling the service with?

The expected XML structure of the request does not match that of the WSDL.

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer. Actually, i tried to to pass XML as string so the exception came.